# is it Possible building an Ionic app into existing Native app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, native

I have a problem. I need to build an ionic application but it has to be able to build a native app. 
The idea is that the Ionic app can be used the kind of standalone. The data with the app needs has to come from the native language. But still, have to feel like it's a mobile app.

So let's say we already have an existing Native mobile app on Android. We just make a new tab there with a Webview. In the Webview, I can run my Ionic app but it still has to communicate with the Android app. Let's say the app needs local storage. Then the Ionic app needs to use the Native local storage from Android. So I have to config the local storage Native. Jet I only want to make the app only once for all the different platforms.

Is this possible? Are they any known ways to make this or any good plugins who can help me doing this?

Answer (score 0):

no, webview not let code to communicate with android native functionality. your code in android webview cant communicate with you app's other functionalities.

Comment: And is it possible when I make a Cordova plugin? But is a Cordova plugin enough to make sure that the Native apps know what they have to do as well or do I need to make a plugin for each platform?

Comment: You wanna create plugin ?? for cordova ?

Comment: Well I just need to find a way to communicate from my ionic app all the way to the Native app. Maybe a Cordova plugin can do it I have no idea at this moment, still have to research that than.